# Help identify this operator

Tags: notation

Except the whole operator is more compact. It is used between two fractions like....  x / y mystery operator x /y . I don't know how to write it on my computer.

```
~
=


text   ~   text
----   =   ----
text       text
```

Comment: It will probably help if you explain what the operator you seek *means*.

Comment: Where did you encounter this?  It sounds like a congruence symbol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\cong$, perhaps? Your question is very hard to understand. $\propto$ is a different symbol that relates to proportionality….

Comment: Sorry when I meant compact i meant it was not two separate symbols. The symbol is the first character in your answer. What does that mean?

Comment: It tends to mean that two things are isomorphic in some sense. For example, in geometry it means they are congruent. What it means in the context of $\frac{\text{text}}{\text{text}} \cong \frac {\text{text}}{\text{text}}$, I haven't the foggiest.

Comment: sorry if the question was poorly written. The problem I was working on was a java program that was using a RandomGenerator to simulate throwing a dart on a dartboard with a square background frame. What i meant by text/ text (mystery symbol) text / text was my book printed darts falling inside circle / darts falling inside square =~ area of circle / area of square.